# Django: Load information from file and edit before saving

Tags: python, django, django-admin, bibtex, bulk-load

I have a bib tex file with a lot of references (books with author, name, year etc.), which I want to import within the django admin and edit them before saving.

At the moment I have a model with a file, where all resources get saved, when I click save. Afterwards I can go to the admin panel, open each reference and edit them manually.

Does somebody know how to load the information into the admin page from the file, so I can edit them before I save the information?

Should look like this. Question would be my file uploader and each Choice (reference) would be prefilled with information from the file. There should not be a foreign key between the file and the references.:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you can do is write `python manage.py collectstatic` which will bring you css and js files. Then you can edit js files if **bib tex** file is **static** then it is easy you can put it somewhere in fron page of admin panel via js. If it is **dynamic** then you can do also, but it will be a bit difficult. But yes You can do.

Comment: No, I meant something different.

I have a file (bib tex) with a lot of references (books with the author, name, year etc.) and I want to import them within django admin. Before saving each reference I want to edit them, because sometimes they have errors. Each reference should appear like the questions in my image.